# Can't send firebase notification via Android but it works via curl

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-notifications

I am trying to send a push notification from one device to another using Firebase (they are two different projects).
I am calling the API via okhttp3 library using POST.
If I try it using curl the notification can be sent but via android I got the following error:

{"multicast_id":XXXXXXXX,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"MismatchSenderId"}]}

Is there some metadata sent with the rest call in Android?
How can I sent

this is the curl call (that works fine)

curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Authorization:key=AXXXXX"  -X POST -d '{"data":{"info":"abc"},"to":"DEV-TOKEN-XXX"}' https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

in Android I just replicate the same scenario setting header, body ecc with okhttp3

Comment: FWIW: You are not really supposed to distribute your server authentication api key to your clients. So only the server is privileged enough to send messages to devices/topics. but you can send upstream messages back to the server. see https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/upstream

Comment: I honestly wouldn't recommend giving clients enough permissions to send a notification to another device. Let a server handle it (ex: device A connects to Server which has all credentials which then sends a notification to device B)

Comment: thanks @herbert and @ ZUNJAE you are right about it, I'll look to implement it in a server. Btw in this case I still want to try to send the notification from the client for testing purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked when I used the "Legacy server key" within Android making a rest call.
But with curl I use the "Server key" and it works fine.
Don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using below way:

1)First get the Token of the device in which you need to send Push Notification

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

2)Then you need to create JSON object having two keys 'to' & 'notification'.You can also use 'data'.which has payload information stored.

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
jsonObj.put("data", profileJson);
jsonObj.put("notification", notificationJson);
jsonObj.put("to", mPushToken);
```

3)Then make an API call which sends push notification.

```
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"), jsonData.toString());
okhttp3.Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder()
        .header("Authorization", "key=" + R.string.firebase_legacy_server_key)
        .url("**https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send**")
        .post(body)
        .build();
```

This will fires push notification to the given firebase token.

Comment: what value does notificationJson contain?